# What is the difference between electromagnetic field and electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory

What is the difference between electromagnetic field and electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: What is the difference between the surface of a pond, and the ripples that spread out over the surface when you drop a stone?

Answer (score 4):

Electromagnetic field is an entity that pervades all space. It may be constant in time, or change in time.

When this entity changes in time in a wavelike manner (for example, there is a field pattern propagating in more-less single direction), we talk about electromagnetic radiation, because the field pattern comes from specific direction, where there is some body producing it - the body *radiates*.

It is common to use the term electromagnetic radiation to refer to any time varying EM field that when propagating to infinity, its amplitude decays with distance from the source slowly enough: mathematically, decaying as function $1/(distance)^2$ (the Coulomb field) is not slow enough, so such field is not thought to manifest radiation, but decaying as function $1/distance$ is slow enough, so such field manifests electromagnetic radiation.

Answer (score 3):

The electromagnetic field is a pair of vectors (or maybe some [other mathematical construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field)) defined at every point in space.

Electromagnetic radiation is a phenomenon we observe in that field, when an excitation in the field propagates through it.

Answer (score 1):

The electromagnetic field consists of electric field and magnetic field vectors whose cross product gives the speed  and direction in which the e m waves travel.But e m radiation is the power radiated by the field, which I think is calculated by cross products of electric and magnetic fields vectors giving what is called as the pointing vector.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right, because the Poynting vector can be nonzero for static fields, where there is clearly no radiation.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning some important fact that as charges begin to accelerate their form of the electric field changes and vector potential gets added in a time derivative form.Thus only accelerating charges or fields produce radiation.This is my opinion please feel free to raise a comment on this.